# Are these Linq-to-Entities expressions identical in their effect?

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

Given `entities` is an `IDbSet<Entity>` and the following expression:

```
entities.Where(e => e.EntityID == 27).AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault();
```

is the below alternate expression identical in effect (removing the `Where` and putting its condition into `SingleOrDefault`):

```
entities.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(e => e.EntityID == 27);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated `SQL` will be the same for both expressions so yes, they are identical. You should pick a convention for your project and stick with it. Personally, and this is just my opinion, I prefer to use `.Where()` as I find it easier to read:

```
entities
    .Where(e => e.EntityID == 27)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Please confirm: the AsNoTracking method will apply to the whole chain no matter where it is, as long as it's still IQueryable, before any switch to IEnumerable? And I personally strongly prefer the removal of Where when using another method that can take the same condition. Make things more wordy when needed, but by Jove, don't do it when you don't have to! Shorter code is easier for me to scan.

Comment: Was just waiting for your response to my comment to select your answer.